# Error Http 400 con Spring MVC

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, controller

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con `Spring MVC` y tengo un error de petición http 400.

La primera vez que llamo al controller login por una petición `get` me redirecciona a la jsp login y después el formulario de la `jsp` me vuelve a llamar al controller login con petición `post` y me redirecciona a otra jsp llamada inicio.

Hasta aquí todo bien, el problema esta en que tengo exactamente otro controller igual a este pero que registra un usuario y cuando el formulario se reenvía con método post me salta el error 400. Muestro el código y por favor díganme si falta algo o porque puede ser.

**Controller de login**

```
  @RequestMapping(value="login",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(ModelMap model){
        UsuarioVO u=new UsuarioVO();
        model.put("usuario", u);
        return "login";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="login",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String loginPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res, @ModelAttribute("usuario")UsuarioVO us,ModelMap model){
        UsuarioVO u=null;
        if(us.getNombreUsuario()==null){
            model.put("error", "Error en la autentificación.Intentelo de nuevo");
            return "login";
        }else{
            u=this.usuarioService.obtenerUsuario(us.getNombreUsuario(), us.getContrasenia());
        }
        if(u.getIdUsuario()==null){
            model.put("error", "Error en la autentificación.Intentelo de nuevo");
            return "login";
        }else{
            model.put("usuario", u);
            model.put("historial", u.getHistorial().getListaContenidos());
            HttpSession session=req.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("usuario", u.getNombreUsuario());
            session.setAttribute("contra", u.getContrasenia());
            try {
                req.getRequestDispatcher("inicio").forward(req, res);
            } catch (ServletException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "inicio";
        }
    }
```

**JSP login**

```
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"            "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
 <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Lista de Peliculas</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Iniciar Sesion</h2>
    <c:if test="${error!=null }"><h2>${error }</h2></c:if>
    <table>
    <form:form modelAttribute="usuario" method="post">
    <tr><td>Nombre Usuario: <form:input path="nombreUsuario"/><td></tr>
    <tr><td>Contrasenia: <form:input path="contrasenia"/><td></tr>
    <tr><td><button type="submit">Iniciar Sesion</button><td></tr>
    </form:form>
    <tr><td><spring:url value="registrarUsuario" var="registrar"/>
    <a href="${fn:escapeXml(registrar) }"><button>Registrar Usuario</button>                </a>
    <td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Controller registrar usuario**

```
    @RequestMapping(value="registrarUsuario" ,method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String registrarse(ModelMap model){
        UsuarioVO u=new UsuarioVO();
        model.put("usuario", u);
        return "usuarios/registrarUsuario";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="registrarUsuario",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registrarsePost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res, @ModelAttribute("usuario")UsuarioVO us,ModelMap model){
        UsuarioVO u=us;
        if(u.getNombre()==null || u.getApellido()==null || u.getContrasenia()==null || u.getNombreUsuario()==null){
            model.put("error", "Error en el registro, debe rellenar todos los campos");
            return "usuarios/regitrarUsuario";
        }else{
            this.usuarioService.insertarUsuario(u);
            model.put("usuario", u);
            model.put("historial", u.getHistorial().getListaContenidos());
            HttpSession session=req.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("usuario", u.getNombreUsuario());
            session.setAttribute("contra", u.getContrasenia());
            try {
                req.getRequestDispatcher("inicio").forward(req, res);
            } catch (ServletException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "inicio";
        }
    }
```

**jsp registrarUsuario**

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="form"         uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Registrar Usuario</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<div>
    <h2>Registrar usuario</h2>
    <c:if test="${error!=null }"><h3>${error }</h3></c:if>
    <table>
    <form:form modelAttribute="usuario" method="post">
    <tr><td>Nombre usuario<form:input path="nombreUsuario"/><td></tr>
    <tr><td>Contrasenia<form:input path="contrasenia"/><td></tr>
    <tr><td>Nombre <form:input path="nombre"/><td></tr>
    <tr><td>Apellidos <form:input path="apellido"/><td></tr>
    <tr><td>Fecha Nacimiento <form:input path="fechaNac"/><td></tr>
    <tr><td><button type="submit">Registrarse</button><td></tr>
    </form:form>
    </table>
</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: antes que nada, debes revisar que el mapeo se hace correctamente, es decir si el jsp esta conectado al método correcto del controlador.

Comment: creo que esta bien conectado, el caso esque si al form le pongo el atributo "action="/registrarUsuario" tambien me sigue diciendo el error 400.